# Pass Oracle ClientID in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I am trying to use the Oracle connection ClientID but I am getting an error msg and I just can't figure out why. Could you please put me on the correct path.

```
cnDB.ConnectionString = OracleDatabase.CnnString();            
            cnDB.Open();
            cnDB.ClientId = "SomeUser";             

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText=strSQL;
            cmd.Connection = cnDB;

Error   23  'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection' does not contain
a definition for 'ClientId' and no extension method 'ClientId'
accepting a first argument of type
'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection' could be found (are you
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

EDIT: Looks like ODP.NET is already used. I am taking over someones code, maybe you can tell me what's wrong here:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

public sealed class OracleDatabase
{
    public static DataTable AllData;
    public const string cnstCnnStrSeparator = ";";

    public static String CnnString()
    {

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader configurationAppSettings = new System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader();
        String strKeyVal;
        strKeyVal = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SecOracle"].ToString();
        return strKeyVal;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string strSQL,bool ConvertToString)
    {
        OracleConnection cnDB = new  OracleConnection();  
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();       

        try
        {

            cnDB.ConnectionString = OracleDatabase.CnnString();            
            cnDB.Open();
          //  cnDB.ClientId = "SomeUser";             

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText=strSQL;
            cmd.Connection = cnDB;             
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;   
            da.Fill(dt);

            DataTable dt1 = dt.Clone();
            if (ConvertToString)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    dt1.Columns[j].DataType = typeof(string);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
                    dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {


                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        dt1.Rows[i][j] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();

                    }

                }

                dt = null;
                AllData = dt1.Copy();
                return dt1;
            }
            else
            {
                dt1 = null;
                AllData = dt.Copy();
                return dt;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnDB.Close();
        }


    }



    public static OracleDataReader GetDataReader(String SQL)
    {

        OracleCommand cmdQuery;
        OracleDataReader dr;
        String str;
        str = CnnString();
        OracleConnection cnDB = new OracleConnection(str);

        cmdQuery = new OracleCommand();
        try
        {

            cmdQuery.Connection = cnDB;
            cmdQuery.CommandText = SQL;
            cmdQuery.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cnDB.Open();
            dr = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            return dr;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            cnDB.Close();
            return null;
        }

        //'

    }

    public static int Execute(String SQL)
    {

        int lngRecords;
        OracleCommand cmdQuery;
        OracleConnection cnDB = null;
        cmdQuery = new OracleCommand();
        try
        {
            cnDB = new OracleConnection(CnnString());
            cmdQuery.Connection = cnDB;
            cmdQuery.CommandText = SQL;
            cmdQuery.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cnDB.Open();
            lngRecords = cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lngRecords = -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnDB.Close();

        }

        return lngRecords;
    }





}
```

Comment: What is `ClientId`? `OracleConnection` doesn't have a property like that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using the Microsoft [System.Data.OracleClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.aspx)  namespace and, as the error message says, there is no ClientID property for the connection.

You should use the [Oracle Data Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) from Oracle and from a specific version forward as you can read from [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=685554&tstart=0) on the OTN Discussion Forum

> ClientID was added to ODP in 10.2.0.1. Yes, you can use 10.2.x ODP and
>   11g ODP against a 9.x database (assuming thats why you installed that
>   version).

Comment: Thank you very much, no wonder I could not find that property.